# Как вывести значение из stdClass Object находящегося в массиве?

Tags: php

Есть массив.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [291980801] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [body] => чого не спиш
                            [mid] => 22430
                            [uid] => 291980801
                            [from_id] => 291980801
                            [date] => 1508795967
                            [read_state] => 0
                            [out] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [body] => рішай саменька, скажеш шо я до Светки приїжав
                            [mid] => 22429
                            [uid] => 291980801
                            [from_id] => 291980801
                            [date] => 1508795369
                            [read_state] => 0
                            [out] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Как перевести stdClass Object в обычный массив?
Ну или как с этого массива оператором `echo` вывести значение из `[291980801][1][mid]` ?

Answer (score 2):

Предположим что ваш массив в переменной $array, тогда доступ к [291980801][1][mid] можно осуществить так:

```
echo $array[0][291980801][1]->mid;
```

Comment: Спасибо, а то что то туплю.